# Can I echo/print out the parameters in this Explode function without using any Iterators functions?

Tags: php

```
<?php
class WebTechnologies
{
    private $tech;

    // constructor
        public function __construct() {
        $this->tech = explode( ',',   'PHP,HTML,XHTML,CSS,JavaScript,XML,XSLT,ASP,C#,Ruby,Python') ;
    }

}
?>
```

i want the echo/print out: PHP,HTML,XHTML,CSS,JavaScript,XML,XSLT,ASP,C#,Ruby,Python

if i have to change $tech to private, please do so.

i got this problem from here btw http://www.sitepoint.com/php-simple-object-iterators/

Comment: Why don't you just continue through that tutorial, and it'll teach you how to do what you're looking to do?

Comment: @TZHX: The tutorial is about using iterators. This question says "without using any Iterators functions". I can't be sure that this sloppy wording means what I think it means, but...

Comment: b/c the rest of the page uses iterators to print out the parameters and i was wondering if there was a different way to do it

Comment: You can use `print_r()` to print the array. It's still entirely unclear why you want to print that list, and why it has to be without iteration. This is an entirely fictional example without use case. (Also: any tutorial that uses `explode(","` instead of just `str_getcsv` might not actually be a good tutorial.)

Comment: @mario: There is nothing wrong with `explode` when you have basic, comma-delimited tokens with no embedded quotes or other fancinesses of the CSV format. Please stop spreading Fear, Uncertainty and Doubt.

Comment: @mario how do i print it out with print_r() ?

Comment: Use [`print_r($var)`](http://php.net/print_r). @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's nothing wrong with using `explode` for frigging everything. There's something wrong with obfuscating tutorials with such sidetracks.

Comment: @mario: Um, switching to the more complex `str_getcsv` in that tutorial would be the obfuscation. _That_ would be the sidetrack.

Answer (score 2):

You've already used `explode` to construct an array from a comma-delimited string.

Now investigate [`implode`](http://php.net/function.implode) which performs the reverse…

Comment: ok i got it 

<?php
class WebTechnologies
{
    private $tech;

    // constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $this->tech = explode( ',',   'PHP,HTML,XHTML,CSS,JavaScript,XML,XSLT,ASP,C#,Ruby,Python') ;
    }

    public function output() {
        echo implode(',', $this->tech);
    }
}

$webtech = new WebTechnologies();
$webtech->output();
?>

Answer (score 1):

Um.

```
<?php
echo "PHP,HTML,XHTML,CSS,JavaScript,XML,XSLT,ASP,C#,Ruby,Python";
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @dan-klasson: Correct!